# Не ясна. НЕ слитно или раздельно?

Tags: частица-не

> Иванов совершает нападки на Петрова. Причина их нам не( )ясна.

"Не ясна" или "неясна"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Замечания к ответу  (для улучшения качества работы форума)**

***Иванов совершает нападки на Петрова. Причина их нам неясна.***

1. Дано **общее решение**, но относительно конкретной задачи **решение отсутствует вовсе.**  Знак вопроса в скобках остался. Что же поставит наш автор, неужели  будет выбирать **наугад?**
2. Представьте, что я сейчас **скопирую текст** правильного общего ответа, а в дальнейшем на все вопросы по этой теме (написание НЕ с краткими прилагательными) буду **использовать эту копию** безо всякого изменения. Поэтому общее решение – это еще не ответ на заданный вопрос: написание НЕ всегда зависит  от структуры конкретного предложения.
3. ***Причина их нам неясна.***  Вполне логично выбрать слитное письмо, так как в предложении  такой структуры  (из четырех слов) обозначить отрицание сложно. Дело в том, что мы должны сделать это не только на бумаге, но в устной речи тоже, иначе это будет только письменный знак.

Если мы по смыслу контекста всё-таки хотим **обозначить отрицание,** то **интонационно** подчеркнуть раздельное написание НЕ можно **в начале предложения**, а в середине предложения следует использовать **усилительные слова,** например:

(1) ***Не ясно, в чем тут причина?***  (2) ***Причина их нам отнюдь не ясна.***

4. **Вывод** (**конкретное решение**  задачи для заданного предложения): в данном случае используется слитное написание НЕ.

Comment: Век живи - век учись! Спасибо!

Answer (score 4):

Краткие прилагательные могут употребляться как слитно с *не*, так и раздельно.

Четких признаков, говорящих об однозначном выборе слитного или раздельного написания, в вашей фразе нет, поэтому решение принимается исходя из контекста:

- если вы хотите подчеркнуть отрицание *ясности*, то *не* пишется раздельно: *Причина их нам не ясна* (возможно вставить слово, усиливающее отрицание: *вовсе не ясна*);
- если вы хотите подчеркнуть утверждение *неясности*, то *не* пишется слитно: *Причина их нам неясна* (возможно вставить слово, усиливающее утверждение: (*очень неясна*).

Из "Правил русской орфографии и пунктуации"<sup>1</sup>:

> §149. (...) при отсутствии в контексте слов, помогающих распознать отрицание или утверждение и, следовательно, отличить частицу *не* от приставки *не-*, пишущий должен проверить, какие слова — усиливающие отрицание или подчеркивающие утверждение — возможны по смыслу в данном контексте. При возможности подстановки слов, выражающих противопоставление или усиливающих отрицание (*вовсе*, *отнюдь* и др.), *не* пишется раздельно, напр.: *Путь туда (отнюдь) не далёкий*; *Погода была (нисколько) не жаркая*; (...)
>
> При возможности подстановки слов, подчеркивающих утверждение (*очень*, *достаточно* и др.), *не* пишется слитно, напр.: *Путь туда (очень) недалёкий*; *Погода была (достаточно) нежаркая*; (...)
>
> Таким образом, пишущий должен отдавать себе отчет в том, что он хочет выразить: отрицание признака или утверждение признака. (...)

---

1. Валгина Н. С., Еськова Н. А., Иванова О. Е., Кузьмина С. М., Лопатин В. В., Чельцова Л. К. Правила русской орфографии и пунктуации. Полный академический справочник / Под редакцией В. В. Лопатина. — 2-е изд., испр. и доп. — М.: Эксмо, 2007.

Comment: Спасибо! Даже не знал, что в правилах так учитывается контекст.